# How can i know if my apache server is using .htaccess or not?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to know if my Apache server uses .htaccess files or not. If it uses them, then why and how?

How can I know if my Apache server is using .htaccess or not?

Thank you.

Comment: test it with a simple file?

Comment: how can i do that? What code should i write to check it?

Comment: write an htaccess file, and check to see if it works

Comment: Yeah but i don't know the basic.. I want to know if apache uses .htaccess or not? and why apache needs to use .htaccess??

Comment: See those negative numbers next your question?  It is getting voted down as off-topic.  This isn't a site for people to write code for you. If you have a specific problem with your existing code, post it, otherwise use your favorite search engine and look for htaccess tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

As for why, it's a convenient way for shared-hosting providers to give some access to users who would like to set some configuration options. You obviously wouldn't want everyone to have access to the main configuration file for security purposes. It's also useful for development purposes since you can set different options for different directories.

As for how Apache uses the file, I recommend [reading the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html).

As for how to know *if* Apache is using .htaccess files, it most likely is. I've yet to meet a shared hosting provider that doesn't. And if you are running your own server, I assume you would know how you set it up. Worst case scenario, you could follow this advice from the docs:

> A good test for this is to put garbage in your .htaccess file and reload the page. If a server error is not generated, then you almost certainly have AllowOverride None in effect.